# Where are key/value pairs for an object stored for a Built-in Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Where are key/value data stored for a builtin class?  They are not accessible with "__dict__" because they are not considered attributes.

Example:

```
class TestNewClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self["item"] = c

x = TestNewClass(3, 4, 5)

print(x.a)          # 3
print(x.b)          # 4
print(x["item"])    # 5
print(x.__dict__)   # {"a": 3, "b": 4} c not considered an attribute
```

Comment: In the instance data structure, and you can access that data with `x['item]'` or `x.__getitem__['item]'`.

Comment: `x.__dict__` is a **separate** dictionary object, there to hold attributes on your instances of your custom class.

Comment: If you just used `x = dict()` or `x = {}`, you'd also create an instance of the type (albeit not a subclass of it), the data is then still stored in the same location: on the Python memory heap for all instances.